# Why my moving button in the div can't react?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a button in a moving div and put an image for background. I also put an animation for div to make it move. However, the button didn't react. I make another button at the button(which for testing and it don't move), it react. Can anyone please help me to solve this problem?

**Here are the codes:**

Html

```
<h1>Animated Aquarium</h1>
<div id="Aquarium">
  <div id="box1">
    <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="jelly fish()">  
      <img src="/img/7959f86c-dccb-410e-b928-73a282b866f1/jellyfish.png"id="jellyfish">
    </button> 
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="jellyfish()">test</button>
</div>
```

Style

```
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #2F80ED, #56CCF2);
  height: 100vh;
}
#Aquarium {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://ak4.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/9874064/thumb/1.jpg");    
}
#box1{
  animation: jellyfishswim 24s infinite;  
  position: absolute;
}
#button1{    
  background-color: inherit;
  border:0px;
}
#jellyfish{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

@keyframes jellyfishswim {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  10% {
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-bottom:200px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  30% {
    margin-left: 420px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  40% {
    margin-left: 560px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 600px;
    margin-top: 420px;
    transform: scaleX(1);}
  60% {
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 340px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  70% {
    margin-left: 420px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  80% {
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  90% {
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}

@keyframes giantjellyfishswim {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  10% {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  20% {
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-bottom:100px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  30% {
    margin-left: 210px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  40% {
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  50% {
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 210px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  60% {
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 170px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  70% {
    margin-left: 210px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  80% {
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
  90% {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

Script

```
function jellyfish() {
  document.getElementById("jellyfish").style.width = "300px";
  document.getElementById("box1").style.animation = "giantjellyfishswim 12s infinite";
  alert("You distory the aquarium");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="jelly fish()">
```

to

```
<button type="button" id="button1" onclick="jellyfish()">
```

```js
function jellyfish() {
    document.getElementById("jellyfish").style.width = "300px";
    document.getElementById("box1").style.animation = "giantjellyfishswim 12s infinite";
    alert("You distory the aquarium");
}
```

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #2F80ED, #56CCF2);
  height: 100vh;
}

#Aquarium {
  width: 700px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 10px solid #000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-image: url("https://ak4.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/9874064/thumb/1.jpg");
}

#box1 {
  animation: jellyfishswim 24s infinite;
  position: absolute;
}

#button1 {
  background-color: inherit;
  border: 0px;
}

#jellyfish {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}



@keyframes jellyfishswim {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  10% {
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  20% {
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  30% {
    margin-left: 420px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  40% {
    margin-left: 560px;
    margin-top: 400px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  50% {
    margin-left: 600px;
    margin-top: 420px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  60% {
    margin-left: 500px;
    margin-bottom: 340px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  70% {
    margin-left: 420px;
    margin-bottom: 300px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  80% {
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-bottom: 200px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  90% {
    margin-left: 120px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}


@keyframes giantjellyfishswim {
  0% {
    margin-left: 0px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  10% {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  20% {
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  30% {
    margin-left: 210px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  40% {
    margin-left: 280px;
    margin-top: 200px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }

  50% {
    margin-left: 300px;
    margin-top: 210px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  60% {
    margin-left: 250px;
    margin-bottom: 170px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  70% {
    margin-left: 210px;
    margin-bottom: 150px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  80% {
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-bottom: 100px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }

  90% {
    margin-left: 70px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    transform: scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="aquarium">
  <div id="box1">
    <button type="button" id="button1" onclick="jellyfish()">  
      <img src="/img/7959f86c-dccb-410e-b928-73a282b866f1/jellyfish.png" id="jellyfish">
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```